Removing corrosion or precipitate from metal post in shower cubical
I am resealing a bit of trim around my shower cubical. A bit of metal trim had to come up (which is not really the problem and all you can see in the image is the place where it went to the right). Then there was a plastic semi-cylinder (with metallic coating) that covered a vertical metal post (shown). The plastic part has been removed in this image. The metal post at the base is where the problem is. There is some black coating, which is either corrosion or a precipitate from water and I want to remove it.

I have had partial luck with scraping with a knife, but this is taking some shavings off the metal also. I've tried a cream cleaner, bathroom spray, vinegar and a metal scouring device (like a wad of metal swarf). The scouring device had a bit of impact but it is slow progress and I'm concerned with damaging the shiny look of the post (most is covered by the plastic simi-cylinder I mentioned, but not all).
I don't know what type of metal is used here. I'm in a hard water area but have a water softer so there is probably sodium in the water also.
The metal bit of trim that I mentioned near the start may be involved in some galvanic corrosion. They were not in direct contact (there is plastic in between), but once the sealant failed, they could touch through the water.
Can anyone suggest a way to clean this off while keeping the post pretty? I have sanding pads up to 400 grit, but no finer. I haven't used these yet.
Many thanks
A

That looks like a chrome (or chrome-like) plating flaking off, or maybe just corroding polished aluminum.  Sanding will only scar the still-good surface.  Do you have any idea what metal the post is made of?

oxidation has occurred under the thin chrome plating  of the metal.  Regardless what metal it is there is no way to renew it to it's original condition.  Your best bet is replacement of the part. Which may be impossible, or cleaning off the oxidation and painting the bottom to look as acceptable to you as possible.

If it's plated it could be removed and sent out for re-plating. Unfortunately that is likely to cost more than replacement in the current economy ;^) If it's (unplated) aluminum and you can remove it you might have a chance at polishing the mess out. I don't give that good odds in place.
